# dynamically add Switches on a View in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need to create a dynamic number of `UISwitch` on a View based on the number of categories that I have on my online database in order to create a "filter".
I've already done the query so I know the number of category and also the category Id (primary key) the problem is that I don't know how to create a dynamic number of Switches based on the number of categories

Comment: You want to change the user interface of Xcode? Sure?

Comment: In iOS or OS X?  Xcode is just the IDE.  If iOS, you want to programmatically create UISwitch controls.  Search for that on SO or Google.  You should find hundreds of answers.  Try something and when you have a specific problem with the code, post that.